# A question in group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $G=AA^g$ for some $g\in G$. Prove $G=A$

I have known that $A^g=g^{-1}Ag$, but I have no idea how to prove $G\subset A$.

Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 3):

First we show that $g\in A$. Since $G=AA^g=Ag^{-1}Ag$, then:

$$Gg^{-1}=Ag^{-1}Agg^{-1}=Ag^{-1}A$$

Additionally $Gg^{-1}=G$, and this follows from the group axioms: namely, $Gg^{-1}\subset G$ by closure, and any element $g'\in G$ is in $Gg^{-1}$ because

$$g'=(g'g)g^{-1}\in Gg^{-1}.$$

Therefore $G=Ag^{-1}A$. In particular, for some $a_1,a_2\in A$ $$e=a_1g^{-1}a_2\implies g=a_2a_1\in A.$$

Now, because $G=Ag^{-1}A$, and $g\in A$, every element of $G$ can be written as the product of elements in $A$, so $G\subset A$. Therefore $G=A$.

Answer (score 1):

You could follow in this line possibly:

Starting with $G=Ag^{-1}Ag$ for some $g\in{G}$ you can cancel $g$ from the RHS:

$Gg^{-1}=Ag^{-1}A$

From which it follows, (after recognizing $A^{-1}=A$ as $A$ is a subgroup of $G$, and that $Gg^{-1}$ is indeed just $G$)

$GA=Ag^{-1}$

Furthermore since the identity is in $A$ and $A$ is a subgroup of $G$ we have $GA=G$, with the final cancellation of $g^{-1}$ on the RHS yields:

$G=A$